# what the result if unused method called several times?

Tags: ios, null

I tried to find out the answer what I want but I couldn't.
I just wonder what will be happened if when I call the method several times but just passing meaningless value 
For example

in .h file

```
UIViewController * v;
```

in .m file

```
-(void) A:(UIViewController*) viewcontroller{

  v = viewcontroller;

}

-(void) B{
   [self A:nil];
}
-(void) C{
   [self A:nil];
}
-(void) D{
   [self A:nil];
}
```

in this case A always get nil.

if this action repeat again and again 
is it okay? or is it bad for memory? if it's bad for memory then how it affects memory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no bad effect on memory because you only have one instance of `UIViewController` in your .h file and you are setting `nil` value to same object.

If you have some looping and inside that you will create some `UIControl`s repeatedly and adding them to your main view or subviews then it may cause memory issues if you have not destroyed/release them properly when you don't need it.